# Testing a form in Cypress, is there a way to listen for when the Submit button 'disabled' attribute is removed?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am testing a new user registration form via the UI and the API using Cypress and am wondering the best approach for testing that the `disabled` attribute remains on the Submit button until all of the required fields are filled in.

All of the fields are required in this case, and the fields are:
Username, Email, and Password

The button code is:

```
<button class="submit-form-btn" type="submit" disabled> Sign up </button>
```

Once all of the fields have been filled out, the `disabled` attribute should disappear and the button becomes enabled.

Does Cypress have a way to *listen* for the `disabled` attribute to disappear?

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to test this other than the obvious:

```
-button should be disabled
-fill in username
-button should be disabled
-fill in email
-button should be disabled
-fill in password
-button should be enabled
```

Comment: you can use   cy.get('.submit-form-btn').should('not.be.disabled');

Answer (score 0):

we use Cypress commands to interact with the form inputs and check the state of the Submit button.

```
it('should enable the button when all required fields are filled', () => {
  cy.visit('/registration-page');
  // Fill in the email
  cy.get('#email-input').type('test@example.com');
  cy.get('.submit-form-btn').should('be.disabled'); 

  // Fill in the password
  cy.get('#password-input').type('examplepassword');
  cy.get('.submit-form-btn').should('not.be.disabled'); // Assert that the button is now enabled
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I'd like to avoid having to assert that the button is still disabled after each field is populated, and am wondering if instead, there might be a way to do this more efficiently. If perhaps there is some kind of listener that will capture when the "disabled" attribute gets removed from the element. Thanks!